# Semaphores and shared memory in linux

Tags: linux, memory, semaphore, shared

I have a bit of a problem at how to synchronize 2 processes. First process must create a shared memory, then wait for the second process to fill the shared memory and signalize it back to the first process. I don't know how to make the first process wait.

Here is a pseudocode of how my processes look like:

Process1:

```
create shared memory
create a semaphore
wait for the second process /* this part i dont know how to write */
output the shared memory
```

Process2:

```
get shared memory id
get the semaphore id
wait();
fill the shared memory 
signalize();
```

Comment: create shared memory and semaphores in process 2 and get shared memory and semaphore id in process1, and do a sem_wait in process1 for the shared memory and do a sem_post in process2 after you copied the data into the shared memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct so far.

As you mentioned in your question you are using semaphore that is the answer to your question.

In posix semaphore api, you have sem_wait() which will wait until value of the semaphore count is zero once it is incremented using sem_post from other process the wait will finish.

In this case you have to use 2 semaphores for synchronization.

**process 1 (reader)**
sem_wait(sem1);
.......

.......
sem_post(sem2);

**process 2(writer)**
sem_wait(sem2);
.......
.......
sem_post(sem1);

In this way you can achieve synchronization in shared memory.

Answer (score 0):

This is hint and not an complete answer.
Use condition variables. See https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#ConditionVariables, that explains how it works. You can work out the solution from there.

Comment: Isn't conditional variables suppose to work only with threads? Or Am I missing something?

Comment: Ok I solved it in a different way. We wait for the other process when we set the value of the sem_op=0;.